# Sub-level sets of $BV$ functions - references and results

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, bounded-variation

I am interested in understanding the set
$$
A := \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \leq 0\rbrace
$$
where $f \in BV(\mathbb{R})$. I know that there is a decomposition of the variational measure in jump part, Cantor part and continuous part. Is there a similar characterization for the set $A$? Can sublevel sets of $BV$ functions be "arbitrarily ugly" or can they only be, say a union of intervals and cantor sets? Also (this might be obvious), with $BV$ functions I mean $L^1$-functions and not pointwise $BV$, so $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}} = 0$ for example.

Is there any literature on this or could you maybe provide a reference? Thank you in advance. Also I don't mind receiving some references on the decomposition result for the measure.

I also know Leoni's and Evans'/Gariepy's books on this, which did not really help me (maybe I missed something). Unfortunately, I don't have access to Ambrosio's book.

Comment: A rather elementary observation is that since BV functions are Baire one functions, then the set in question is a $G_{\delta}$ set. This follows from the easy half of the characterization of Baire one functions as those with the property that for each real number $\alpha$ the inverse images of $\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \leq \alpha \rbrace$ and $\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \geq \alpha\rbrace$ are $G_{\delta}$ sets -- see Theorem 4 (top p. 15) [here](https://www.whitman.edu/documents/Academics/Mathematics/huh.pdf). I don't know whether anything stronger must be true for BV functions.

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you